# How to Create Scene using Normal & Retina Display using Cocoa Builder?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I have started working on cocos2d-iphone. but now i am also trying to use cocoa builder to create UI & Animation. which is also working fine with me. but i have created a scene for normal ipad which is working fine. but in retina it showing me half images. so do i needs to create another one ccbi file for retina or is there any functionality which is provided by cocoa builder?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhaaa,

I found my answer, just needs to images with suffix  add "-ipad" for normal & "-ipadhd" for retina display.